# OpenGL transparent background Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm building an application who stream the content of the camera on the screen. Now I want to add a OpenGL element on the screen. My OpenGL element is an arrow that I create in a other class, that inherit GLKView call TriangleView. My ViewController is a GLKViewController. I add my Triangle View like this

`View = triangleView = new TriangleView (View.Frame);`

That draw my GLKView, but I would like to have a transparent background for this GLKView in order to see my camera stream. I'm beginning in OpenGL so I don't really know how to do that. I found some post that say to put an alpha on it`GL.ClearColor (1.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);`,in the Draw function of my GLKView, but this doesn't work.

Any help or comment is welcome.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to set the GLKView's opaque property to NO so the alpha blending can work.